# why does this print? (C language)

Tags: c, loops, printing, while-loop

Why does the following code run the while loop? I thought "mid = term" is an assignment, not a condition? Please explain. Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main ()
{
    int mid = 4, term = 4;

    while ( mid = term)
    printf("%d\n", --term);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The result of an assignment is the value.  Therefore the expression evaluates to `4` or a non-zero and thus, in C, `TRUE`.

Answer (score 5):

`mid = term` is an expression evaluating to `term`. So the while loop will run till `term = 0`.

Answer (score 2):

Because the expression evaluates to true.

Basically, you are saying `mid = 4`

Since any int that isn't zero, returns true in a conditional statement - the while will loop.

Comment: it won't loop forever, just 4 times. The assignment will be evaluated on each iteration of the `while` loop and since `term` is being decremented within the loop it will quit when `term == 0`

Answer (score 1):

The expression `mid = term` actually evaluates to the value of `mid` after assignment. So, what's being evaluated is `while(4)`. Since all nonzero integers are interpreted as `true` (this is kind of a simplification), the while loop will run as long as `term != 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Both the assignment and the test happen in the "`while`" loop, so the `printf()` executes four times in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Assignment are also expressions which hold a value: the value they assign. `mid=0` is an expressions that evals to `0` (thus false).

Answer (score 0):

You assign `term` to `mid` and then test the truth of `mid`. `mid` is truthy whenever it is non-zero.  The loop terminates when `term` (and hence `mid`) has been decremented to equal 0, which is falsy.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the value of `term` to `mid`, then the `while` checks the value of `mid` which evaluates to true, until it reaches 0.

This should output:

```
3
2
1 
0
```